# Making a php blogsite

Tags: php, blogs

I am php web developer. well, am new. I want to create a blog-site for a writer, but I don't know how to make the site text editable. So, am asking, how do I optimize my php site for texts contents, and also probably other media contents.

Thanks

Comment: why reinvent wheel? use wordpress, silverstripe, ...

Comment: Hi. Your question is not specific. However the only tip that I can give you is you can use text editors for handling all the text formats as well as images.

Comment: wordpress man best for blog.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use wordpress. The user can create,edit and destroy content and you will be able to style that information. Check this [link](https://romualdfons.com/tutorial-wordpress/)